# Is there any daemon which constantly monitors system and execute script?

Tags: monitor, services, notification

Is there any daemon in ubuntu which constantly monitors system and execute script for specified cases (Like RAM uses increased 90%)?

My soul purpose is to get a notification whenever resource consumption increases sharply.

Comment: This is not a good solution, but you may use anacron to run the script every, say, 30 seconds, and, in script, use some sensors app to check the resorce.

Comment: I swear I saw something here just the other day that did this from a graphical setting. I can't find it but it memory serves, it was a Qt application that you could set CPU and free memory thresholds to trigger scripts. Hopefully somebody else can remember what it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely want to setup either [Nagios](http://nagios.org) or it's most recent fork [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org/). Nagios is a monitoring solution that can run locally or on remote machines (if you manage multiple machines in a network). You configure which services to monitor and the threshold for being notified. There are even ways to have fall back procedures in place - for instance: if a service fails you can have Nagios attempt to restart it X times before finally notifying you.

I'm not sure if Icinga is in the repos yet, but Nagios has been for quite sometime now.